# Get the current Object in its own properties - Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

How can you get the currently selected object in its own properties?

In the example bellow I want to send the currently selected StopLine to a function on each vehicle pass.

Using the ***this*** fucntion only returns the parent object - main.

I was hoping there is a simple function to return the object without having to directly input the current object.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "self". For such questions, the light bulb is your best friend. Refer to the following article:

https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling